# Leket in the Peah Zone

Tags: leket-shichecha-peah

A pauper is gathering grain in the "Peah" zone - the corner of the field set aside by the owner for the poor.

If he drops a piece of wheat, may he pick it up, or does he have to leave it as Leket for another pauper to take?

Comment: Minchas chinuch mitzvah 218:1 says that if you take something from hefker there’s no leket.

Comment: Are leket and peah truly hefker, or are they reserved for the poor?

Comment: I’m not sure, but I don’t think it makes a difference. His reasoning is that since it’s not meshumar it’s patur from leket.